# MariaDB SELECT arithmetic operation based on type

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, calculation

I have following query in MariaDB

```
MariaDB [nova]> SELECT hostname, instances.created_at, 
  SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,instances.created_at, NOW())) AS 'Total Hours',  
  JSON_EXTRACT(flavor, '$.cur."nova_object.data".name') AS FLAVOR  
 FROM instances  
 JOIN instance_extra ON instances.uuid = instance_extra.instance_uuid  
 WHERE (vm_state='active' OR vm_state='stopped') 
  AND hostname LIKE '%bfbxp%' 
 Group by FLAVOR;
+------------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
| hostname         | created_at          | Total Hours | FLAVOR         |
+------------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
| www5             | 2022-11-17 15:44:32 |       14703 | "gen.medium"   |
| www6             | 2022-11-17 15:44:26 |        3678 | "gen.large"    |
| www7             | 2022-11-17 15:44:46 |        7350 | "sriov.medium" |
+------------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.007 sec)
```

I want to apply costing per hour calculation `Total Hour * Cost` and following cost i have for each FLAVOR. How do i apply that in SQL query or i should use scripting like python or bash to do complex query?

`"gen.medium"` cost `$0.050` so do `3578*0.50`

`"gen.large"` cost `$0.060` so do `14703*0.60`

`"sriov.medium"` cost `$0.070` so do `7350*0.70`

I was thinking i can create #temp table and add costing of each flavor in that table and join two table and run calculation. Does that sounds easy?

Comment: I think that common CASE operator usage will be more simple and even more fast.

Comment: Use json_unquote on the results of json_extract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT hostname, 
       instances.created_at, 
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,instances.created_at, NOW())) AS `Total Hours`,  
       JSON_EXTRACT(flavor, '$.cur."nova_object.data".name') AS flavor  

,      SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,instances.created_at, NOW())) 
           * CASE JSON_EXTRACT(flavor, '$.cur."nova_object.data".name')
                 WHEN '"gen.medium"'   THEN 0.5
                 WHEN '"gen.large"'    THEN 0.6
                 WHEN '"sriov.medium"' THEN 0.7
                 END AS `Total Cost`

FROM instances  
JOIN instance_extra ON instances.uuid = instance_extra.instance_uuid  
WHERE vm_state IN ('active', 'stopped') 
  AND hostname LIKE '%bfbxp%' 
GROUP BY flavor;
```

> If cost will change in 2024 you want to update your application instead of data? – Georg Richter

```sql
CREATE TABLE weights 
SELECT '"gen.medium"' code, 0.5 weight, 2023 `year` UNION ALL
SELECT '"gen.large"'      , 0.6       , 2023
SELECT '"sriov.medium"'   , 0.7       , 2023;
```

```sql
SELECT hostname, 
       instances.created_at, 
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,instances.created_at, NOW())) AS `Total Hours`,  
       JSON_EXTRACT(flavor, '$.cur."nova_object.data".name') AS flavor  

,      SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,instances.created_at, NOW())) * weights.weight AS `Total Cost`

FROM instances  
JOIN instance_extra ON instances.uuid = instance_extra.instance_uuid  
JOIN weights ON JSON_EXTRACT(flavor, '$.cur."nova_object.data".name') = weights.code
WHERE vm_state IN ('active', 'stopped') 
  AND hostname LIKE '%bfbxp%' 
  AND weights.`year` = 2023
GROUP BY flavor;
```

Comment: If cost will change in 2024 you want to update your application instead of data? Cost is never constant (except for free beer :-)

Comment: That is why i was thinking if i create new tables and add flavor and related cost in tables and write smart query which will pull data from both tables and give nice output. I would like like it to breakdown in every month so convert hours in 30day and find out monthly costing. but that would be best step.

Comment: @Satish I do not see a problem to convert hardcoded data to one more data source. A variant added.